# Midpoints of Cevians

Tags: geometry, triangles

In triangle $\triangle ABC$, $D$ and $E$ lie on sides $CA$ and $AB$ such that $BE = 6$ and $CD = 10$. Let $M$ and $N$ be the midpoints of segments $BD$ and $CE$, respectively. If $MN = 7$, then what is the measure of $\angle BAC$?

I'm not sure how to start this, I can't find any similar or parallel lines in the figure. I can construct the trapezoids but I do not know how to utilize them.

Comment: Could you provide a picture?

Comment: sorry no picture was given in the problem

Comment: You could make one with geogebra for instance; that would make the problem more attractive... And please consider using $\LaTeX$

Answer (score 1):

If $A=E=D$, then triangle $MAN$ has sides $3$, $5$ and $7$. From the cosine rule it follows that
$$
\cos\angle MAN={3^2+5^5-7^2\over 2\cdot 3\cdot 5}=-{1\over2},
\quad\text{that is:}\quad \angle MAN=\angle BAC=120°.
$$
This is a particular case, but the problem implies that the same solution must hold also in the general case.

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by A =E = D?

Comment: See my edit: I had written by mistake $E$ and $D$ instead of $M$ and $N$, I corrected and added a picture.